Are the companions of prophet eesa in second coming better than tabaeen?
The report of musnad Ahmed 3600 tells, companions are the best people after prophets.

He looked at the hearts of His servants after Muhammad, and He found that the hearts of his companions were the best among them

Additionally, ibn taymiyyah opines "if you ask the Jews who are the best people, they would say the companions of moses. If you ask the Christians, they would say the companions of jesus"
This is inline with the summary given by report of  musnad Ahmed 3600 terming the companions of ulul azam(best 5 prophets) being best after prophets.
Based on the above we see that during the second coming of prophet eesa we have a new batch of companions. Also they endure the greatest fitna called Dajjal and fitna of gog and magog
Does this mean the companions of prophet Eesa in his second coming better than tabaeen (second generation of this ummah)?

There's no evidence that the companions of all Prophets or ulul 'adhm were great people. In fact, some Prophets have had fasiqeen as companions. The companions of the Prophet Mohammad PBUH were, however, of exemplary character as Allah even states it in the Quran as "best nation produced for mankind", but no such statement has been made for the nations or companions for the previous Prophets. On the contrary, some fasiqeen in the companions of previous Prophets have been mentioned, like Musa alayhissalam, and-.

it is debatable whether Isa alayhissalam's previous companions (or at least some of them) were loyal to him or not. Perhaps there has elapsed too much time to analyze this so we can have some husn u dhann, but, past scholars have spoken against the companions of Isa alayhissalam.

Abdullah bin Ubai bin Salool isnt considered a companion. Hypocrites arent companions.

And I didn't say he was considered one? Fasiqeen and munafiqeen are not the same. Abdullah Ibn Ubayy wasn't only a fasiq, but a munafiq as well.
